# How to pass a variable in array index

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing

i repeat the title because everything is there : How to pass a variable in array index

```
var xyz = 0;
var somearray = ['a','b','c'];
var content = somearray[xyz]; - **that dont work !**
```

what should be the RIGHT way to do that ?

Comment: actually the above does work (at least in my test in firebug I get content = 'a'). What about the above isn't working for you?

Comment: works heres a [demo](http://jsbin.com/odece4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That actually is correct.  After executing your code, minus the comment, content contains 'a'.

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>Test</title>
</head> 
<body>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var xyz = 0;
    var somearray = ['a','b','c'];
    var content = somearray[xyz];
    alert(content);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You should get a nice little alert box that says "a".

Comment: Did you cut and paste your actual code into your question?  Or retype it?  You might have a typo in your running source, or a mis-cased character.

Answer (score 1):

Just a stab in the dark here, but perhaps the OP is using inArray and might be asking (indirectly) how to get the intellisense working in whatever tool they're using.

If that's the case, I'm sure someone here can provide a more elegant solution but something similar to the following should work:

```
var somearray = ['a','b','c'];
var index = $.inArray('a', somearray);
if (index > -1) {
    index = isNaN(index) ? 0 : index;
    var content = somearray[index];
}
```

Comment: A helpful answer, but inferring a lot more from the question than I think one can so it seems as though you are offering a really helpful answer to a different question.